# Prioritizing Github Copilot suggestions over snippet tab stops

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, github-copilot

I often find myself wanting to accept a Github Copilot suggestion in the middle of a snippet. But every time I press tab to accept the suggestion, my cursor just goes to the next tab stop in the snippet. This is especially problematic when you have lots of language specific snippets included in VSCode extensions.

For instance, in ruby there's a simple snippet included in the VSCode Ruby extension:

```
def $1
  $2
end
```

When I use this snippet and my cursor is at the $1 position, and Copilot gives me a correct suggestion that I want to accept, and I press tab, the cursor always just goes to the next tab stop (the $2) position, and rejects the Copilot suggestion.

This behavior is the same when I simply have just one tab stop, like this custom user snippet:

```
console.log($1)
```

In this case, it always just goes from the $1 position to the end of the snippet (after the second parenthesis).

So is there a way I can make it so Copilot suggestions will be prioritized over going to the next cursor position in the snippet? Or another solution would be to just configure a different trigger for accepting the suggestion (like ctrl + enter). But using a different shortcut for this trigger doesn't seem to be an option, at least in the docs I've seen.

Are there any ways to achieve this behavior? It seems like a super common use case.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a way to change the behavior of `Tab`.
Meaning, Visual Studio Code does not provide a built-in way to prioritize GitHub Copilot suggestions over snippet tab stops.

As a workaround, you can try a suggestion from [discussions 7012](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/7012): changing the keybinding for accepting suggestions.

You would need to:

1. Open the Command Palette with `Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Cmd+Shift+P` on macOS.
2. Type `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`.
3. In the search bar, type `acceptSelectedSuggestion` to find the command.
4. Click on the pencil icon next to the command to edit it.
5. Press the key combination you want to use for accepting suggestions.
   For example, you could use `Ctrl+Enter`.

This way, you can use the `Tab` key for navigating through snippet tab stops and `Ctrl+Enter` (or any other key combination you prefer) for accepting GitHub Copilot suggestions.